# onTouch() isn`t called, even when I Touch the screen?

Tags: android

my on Touch() method never gets called, even if I touch the screen, do you know why?

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent ev) {
    Log.v("drawing", "Touched");
    return true;
}
```

and here the class

```
public class Run extends Activity implements Drawer, OnTouchListener{
```

Comment: post the whole `Run ` clas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently in your code u didn't set any setOnTouchListener to any view or layout.
for example, your touch method has to work on, add the setOnTouchListener for ur xml layout in ur code.

```
AbsoluteLayout mainLayout // i'm using absolute layout in xml , change according to ur xml main layout
mainLayout = (AbsoluteLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);//reffer the id
mainLayout.setOnTouchListener(this);//set listener
```

now touch the screen and check the log ..

Answer (score 0):

`onTouch` in `Activity` will almost never be called, except if *none* of the `View`s consume the touch event.

Instead, if you *really* want your `Activity` to handle touch events, listen for touch events in `onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent)`.

An interesting talk on this: [Mastering the Android touch system](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI).